# Change the transparency of sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext

Can I change the transparency of **sublime text 2**?

Comment: For linux users http://askubuntu.com/questions/133286/how-can-i-make-my-windows-transparent-by-doing-altmouse-scroll

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Looks like this isn't a feature](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5909), but you can [vote for it here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/50259-background-transparency-at-the-color-scheme-level/), and you can [work around it here](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/).

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Windows you can install following st2/st3 plugin:

https://github.com/vhanla/SublimeTextTrans

You can install either manually or via install package plugin.

You can also change SublimeTextTrans.sublime-settings file so you can overwrite default levels of transparency. Package resource viewer plugin will help you to find this file easily.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no support for transparent backgrounds.  You can probably achieve this with a third party application. For example, on MacOS X you can look at [Afloat](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/).

Comment: Anything for linux - ubuntu??

Answer (score 1):

On windows, I oftenly use **Peek Through**. It does work great with Sublime Text as well as with any other application.

Just install it and run it.

http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/projects/peek-through/

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Ctr+Shift+P
- Install Package
- Transparency

User: Preferences

Comment: This plugin is only for Windows, at the moment.